# Simple Joomla Plugin or Module to print premade text into text editor

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, joomla-extensions

i was wondering if you guys could point out and give me some ideas on how to make a simple joomla module or plugin which would do the following function

1. clicking a button would popup a simple form with 3 text boxes
2. upon submission of the form those filled text variables along with some more preconfigured text to be printed into the joomla text editor so that the client can just submit the article without having to type anything.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest checking out the **Regular Labs (NoNumber) Content Templater**: https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/contenttemplater

It doesn't have a popup form, but it puts a simple button/dropdown at the bottom of the editor where they can just select the set template they want.  That template can be set blocks of text, article settings, etc